# Strange behaviour of telerik (rad)gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

I have a WPF application with a GridView bound to an IQueryable<> collection wich is loaded directly from a database table.
This table holds some TEXT fields. Problem is that the GridView automatically increases all rows according to the length of 
the TEXT field's value. Meanang that if the TEXT field's value has 5 lines of some text, proper GridView row increases its 
height and shows all 5 lines. I need the GridView to have all rows of the same static height just for a single line of text
(with an ellipsis button for TEXT field). Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid auto-generated columns and set manually the column widths. It should prevent that behavior.

If you want to go further, you can assign a template to cells and put in the template a text that does not wrap.

Best regards